# Android SSH client with remote command support

Tags: android, ssh, sourceforge

I would like to be able to use SourceForge's SSH [shell service](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Shell%20service) with my Android smartphone so I installed ConnectBot. But for creating a shell on SF, I need to pass the remote command 'create', which sadly doesn't work with the 'Post-login automation' option...

Is there any SSH client for Android that supports remote commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called ServerAssistant.

https://market.android.com/details?id=org.openobjectives.serverassistant&feature=search_result

Answer (score 1):

Or "Admin Hands", can do what you asking for in batch mode also: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arpaplus.adminhands